# How can I display string returned by a Apex class method on VisualForce pages?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, bestpractice

I have written the following Apex class. Now, I wish to display the string returned by `getMonthsString()` on VisualForce Pages.

Here is the Apex class:

```
public class MyFirstClass {
    public static List<String> months = new List<String>{'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec'};

    public static String getMonthsString() {
        String output = '';
        for(String month : months) {
            output += month + '>';
        }
        output = output.removeEnd('>');
        return output;
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyFirstClass">
    ???
</apex:page>
```

Which standard component can I use to display the required result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use outputText component

```
<apex:page controller="MyFirstClass">
    <apex:outputText value="{!MonthsString}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is correct. But what if the function name was `outputMonthString()` (a method without prefix `get`)?

Comment: As long as it returns a string, you could just use `"{!outputMonthString}"`